# JavaFX: How to populate data to TableView from different Thread(Netty)

Tags: java, multithreading, tableview, javafx-8, netty

I have below code. the tableview does not display record on GUI,is empty.
How I can Pass value from the ServerHandler thread to JAVAFX UI thread.

Can you please suggest? 
Thanks

**UPDATE**

The Main class

```
public class Main extends Application {
private static Stage stage;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("mainpane.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.load();
    setStage(primaryStage);
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.getRoot(); 
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(() -> launch(Main.class, args)).start();
    new MyServer().startDownload();
}
```

The Controller

```
public class SampleController {
private ObservableList<Model> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@FXML
private TableView<Model> table;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Model, String> firstCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Model, String> secondCol;   
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    table.setEditable(false);
    firstCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getName());
    secondCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCurrent());
    table.setItems(tableData);
}
public void addModel(ChannelFuture sendFileFeture,Model model){
    table.getItems().add(Model);
    System.out.println("row model= "+model.getName().get());// it works fine;
    sendFileFeture.addListener(model);
}
```

The Server class with Netty 4

```
public class ServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest>{
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest msg) throws Exception {
    //some codes
    Model model=new Model(file.getName(),fileLength+"");
    SampleController sc=new SampleController();
    sc.addModel(sendFileFeture, model);
}
```

The Model class with ChannelProgressiveFutureListener of Netty

```
public class Model implements ChannelProgressiveFutureListener{
private SimpleStringProperty name=null;
private SimpleStringProperty current=null;

public Model(String name,String current){
    this.name=new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    this.current=new SimpleStringProperty(current);
}

@Override
public void operationProgressed(ChannelProgressiveFuture future, long progress, long total) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("current: "+current+",progress: "+progress); //it works fine
    current.set(progress+""); // can not update the TableView
}
@Override
public void operationComplete(ChannelProgressiveFuture future) throws Exception {
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}
public SimpleStringProperty getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setCurrent(String current) {
    this.current.set(current);
}
public SimpleStringProperty getCurrent() {
    return current;
}
```

### **UPDATE**

the tableview not updating with right size,the image i loaded is 2,407,257 bytes.you can find the errors in the images below.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ2NR.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeWeR.jpg)

```
secondCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCurrent());
secondCol.setCellFactory(column -> {return new TableCell<Model, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                System.out.println(item); //UPDATING NOT CURRECT
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(empty ? "" : getItem().toString());
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI is not displaying anything because you are populating a different table to the one you are displaying, not because of threading (though you have threading issues too, or will do once you fix the initial problem).

In your `start()` method, you load the FXML, which creates a `TableView` and its columns, and creates a controller instance. Your `ServerHandler` class creates a new instance of the controller, which in turn creates a new instance of `TableView` (it is *always* a mistake to initialize variables that are annotated `@FXML`). That `TableView` instance is never displayed. So when your `ServerHandler` populates the table, it is populating a table that is not actually part of the UI, and you don't see anything.

Move the creation of the `MyServer` to the `start()` method, and pass it the existing controller instance:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage stage;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("mainpane.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.load();
        setStage(primaryStage);
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.getRoot(); 
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        SampleController controller = loader.getController();
        new Thread(() -> new MyServer(controller).startDownload()).start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Your `MyServer` class should in turn pass the controller to the `ServerHandler` instance(s). Since the `ServerHandler` methods are being invoked on a background thread, they need to use `Platform.runLater(...)` to update the UI:

```
public class ServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest>{

    private final SampleController sc ;

    public ServerHandler(SampleController sc) {
        this.sc = sc ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest msg) throws Exception {
        //some codes
        Model model=new Model(file.getName(),fileLength+"");
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            sc.addModel(sendFileFeture, model);
            sc.addRowModel(sendFileFeture, rowModel);
        });
    }

}
```

Finally, don't initialize fields that are supposed to be initialized by the `FXMLLoader`. This will only have the effect of suppressing any `NullPointerException`s that indicate your controller-FXML bindings are not properly set up:

```
public class SampleController {

    private ObservableList<Model> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    private TableView<RowModel> table ;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Model, String> firstCol ;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Model, String> secondCol ;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        table.setEditable(false);
        firstCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getName());
        secondCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getProgress());
        table.setItems(tableData);
    }
    public void addModel(ChannelFuture sendFileFeture,Model model){
        table.getItems().add(model);
        System.out.println("row model= "+model.getName().get());// it works fine;
        sendFileFeture.addListener(rowModel);
    }

}
```

Comment: there is a problem with  updating of table column,can you please let me know how fix it ? Thanks

Comment: @uidin I didn't notice this before, but why are the types for the table and the tablecolumns different? (You have `TableView<RowModel>` but `TableColumn<Model, ...>`). And what is `current`?

Comment: sry,my fault, I edited the code.i tried two models,but they are all with String,the currect is  `TableView<Model,String>`.The "current" is length of a File,with current/progress in operationProgressed method i calculate percentage of progress，you can ignore this "current".

Comment: The problem is,the second tablecolum in first row display incorrect value,after second row load or i srcoll,it change to the correct number.i posted two screenshots,maybe can help understanding